# Create Layout with absolute Values and Flexbox in React Native

Tags: react-native, layout, react-native-flexbox

I am a iOS Developer trying to learn React Native. Currently I am trying to figure out how to create a layout like this with FlexBox:

[image: LayoutGoal]

I am not sure how to use relative values for with in react native. When I am trying to implement it I am getting this:

[image: Wrong Layout]

As you can see, the view in the middle cutting the views on the left and right at there center. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1}}>
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{left: 20, top: 24, height: 44, width: 44}}>
        <Image
          source={require('../../assets/images/backButton.png')}
          style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
    <View style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: '#FF2F2F'}}></View>
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text
        style={{
          right: 20,
          top: 24,
          height: 44,
          fontSize: 14,
        }}>
        1 / 6
      </Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you have incorrectly ordered the classes(View, SafeView, etc) which are causing the layout to overlap and preventing you from getting the desired result.

Check my solution proposed below:

```
return (
  <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, height: "100%"}}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{height: 44, width: 44, margin: 10}}>
        <Image
          source={require('../../assets/images/backButton.png')}
          style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FF2F2F'}}></View>
      <Text
        style={{
          padding: 14,
          fontSize: 14,
        }}>
        1 / 6
      </Text>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```

[Running example for the solution on expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@gavindmello97/view_intending)

*Feel free to explore and edit it!*

Comment: The issue is that the top, left, and right style values explicitly directed the image and text to overlap with the red box. Which you removed. SafeAreaView does not contain insets for the left and right of the phone screen, only areas `covered by navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars, and other ancestor views`